# How to force user to properly close sqlite connexion

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to make an SqliteHelper that would force any user to close properly the connexion after executing a query.

Is there a pattern that would ensure this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try is to make helper methods that require the user actions to be supplied as a lambda expression or method reference. I'm not sure how you're connecting to SQLite, so I'll use JDBC classes in my example:

```
public static void doAction(Consumer<Connection> userAction) {
   try (Connection conn = /* logic to create connection */) {
      userAction.accept(conn);
   }
   // Connection automatically closed due to try-with-resources
}
```

A user could then do the following:

```
SqliteHelper.doAction(conn -> {
  // Logic that uses connection
});
```

One problem with this approach is that `Consumer` requires you to catch exceptions within the lambda body. If this isn't what you want you could define your own functional interface that allows exceptions:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SqliteOperation {
   void perform(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
}
```

The `doAction` method then needs a slight tweak:

```
public static void doAction(Consumer<Connection> userAction) {
   try (Connection conn = /* logic to create connection */) {
      userAction.accept(conn);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      // Log the error, wrap it in another exception, just don't ignore it
   }

   // Connection automatically closed due to try-with-resources
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. could you detail `Connection automatically closed due to try-with-resources` ?

Comment: Of course! Assuming your connection class implements `AutoCloseable` then wrapping the connection in a try-with-resources block will ensure its `close` method is automatically called at the end of the `try` block (regardless of whether any exceptions are thrown)

Comment: amazing. Did not know about this !